# Spark executes joins sequentially even though they are submitted in parallel threads

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I run 4 parallel threads on the driver node in Spark that do the same thing but with different data. Spark does execute all the submitted jobs in parallel up to the point where there is a join. At that point the join actions are done sequentially.
This is what the SparkUI shows:
[image]

Is there anything i can do to make the joins run in parallel?

### UPDATE:

The command I use to start the process is:

```
spark-submit  
   --master local[16]  
   --class ...  
   --driver-memory 11G  
   --conf spark.default.parallelism=4  
   --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4
```

I use only 4 partitions because the data I process is very small (2-3MB).
For the time being I am testing in local mode.
For production I will use an EMR cluster.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, maybe make the [tour] and be sure to read [ask]. You may improve your question by adding a [mcve]

Comment: How are you launching this job into the cluster? Show us the command you are using. My guess is that since a join operation requires data to be shuffled around there is not enough resources to perform multiple jobs simultaneously.

Comment: Hi #MBillau, I added the start command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was persisting the data immediately after the join. After removing the persist, the joins were done in parallel.